# How can I write safe java.util.Optional null pointer assignment when getting aList.get(0)?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have the following code that throws when my call to .getList().get(0) is null.

```
Optional<MyObject> _obj = java.util.Optional.ofNullable(objParam);

// where getListOfMyObjects() returns List<MyObjects>
Optional<String> desc = Optional.ofNullable(_obj.get().getMyParentObject().getListOfMyObjects().get(0).getDesc());
```

How can I write safe java 8 Optional code (use .map, etc,.) that will prevent .getList().get(0) from throwing?

Comment: Please post a compilable code. What is `obj`? Where is `getMainObj()` method?

Comment: Instead, I would fix the bug: a method returning a List should never return null.

Comment: please do see updates. thx

Comment: @JBNizet they aren't my domain objects.

Comment: @JaJ Still, that isn't a compilable code.

Comment: @RohitJain what isn't compatible about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
Optional<String> desc = Optional.ofNullable(objParam)
        .map(MyObject::getMyParentObject)
        .map(MyObject::getListOfMyObjects)
        .filter(lst -> ! lst.isEmpty())
        .map(lst -> lst.get(0))
        .map(MyObject::getDesc);
```

Another way to do it is by getting the list's `stream` and then using `findFirst`.  I am not sure if using streams inside optional is very clear, but here's how you would do it:

```
Optional<String> desc = Optional.ofNullable(objParam)
        .map(MyObject::getMyParentObject)
        .map(MyObject::getListOfMyObjects)
        .map(List::stream)
        .flatMap(Stream::findFirst)
        .map(MyObject::getDesc);
```